# Workers started successfully dataflow flex template but sanbox stopped reduced the number of workers with autoscaling

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow flex template and started a run (gcloud flex-template run...) with 3 workers. This workers started successfully but the sandbox launcher stops and my autoscalling resized the workers to 1, as the image below:

[Logging Google Cloud Dataflow flex-template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lafs8.png)

After this, the job runs normally with 1 worker and autoscalling resize the number of workers normally. Why it's happenning? I really need that my job start with 3 workers and autoscale if needs

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y git




#Copy all files in current directory and send to /dataflow/template
COPY . /dataflow/template

#Define the /app directory as work directory
WORKDIR /dataflow/template

ENV DATAFLOW_PYTHON_COMMAND_SPEC="/dataflow/template/python_command_spec.json"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="/dataflow/template/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="/dataflow/template/setup.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="/dataflow/template/main.py"


#INSTALL REQUIREMENTS
#install apache-beam[gcp] outside of the requirements.txt to speed up the launch container
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libffi-dev git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # install the requirements and upgrade pip
    && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install keyring \
    && pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir apache-beam[gcp]==2.38.0 \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    # Download the requirements to speed up launching the Dataflow job.
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE


#Since we already downloaded all the dependencies, there's no need to rebuild everything.
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your job is launched, there is no need to keep the sandbox up. The fact that it's adjacent to the autoscaling log is just a coincidence--it determined that there was barely any work left to do for this stage and so it downsized the pool.

Are you seeing different behavior if you launch this pipeline from a template vs. manually? If not, it may be easier to debug the issue without templates in the loop regardless of your final method of deployment.

Comment: When I run the job using the dockerfile of custom container https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers?hl=pt-br

My job starts 3 workers and run imediattly the pipeline, but when I use the image of flex template my job starts with 3 workers but Before the start to run the pipeline script, he resize to 1 worker because, i guess, the gap time between the "Finished operation read from jdbc/Userquery" and "Workers have started successfully" take so much time